# How to exclude dim background from cover status bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I'm using a DialogFragment, with a custom view, and when it's displayed, the dim background cover the whole screen, even setting android:fitsSystemWindows="true" on the activity that calls it.

Is there any way to prevent the dim background from covering the status bar?

Code below shows how I'm creating the DialogFragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog_fragment, container, false);

    ...

    return rootView;    
}
```

calling this way:

```
DialogFragment dialog = new MyFragmentDialog();
FragmentManager fm = this.getFragmentManager();
dialog.show(fm, tag);
```

Comment: I have been trying to do the same for a while now, still haven't figured out without hardcoding padding to the system bar height, which is not ideal

Comment: I have same problem